# Device Id not storing in server IOS7

Tags: ios, push-notification, devicetoken

In my application i have added notification by storing the device id in server and using php i sending notification the problem is now device token is not storing in the server previously it was working f9 but not its not working.

Previously I was using different account now I'm accessing different account after setting the new account certification in my app is not working please tell where I'm wrong.

Notification code.

```
      - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
       return YES;
     }


    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
   {

    const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString * token = [NSMutableString string];

   for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
   }


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url?token=%@",token];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"token %@",urlString);


    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"request %@ ",urlRequest);
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];    
    NSLog(@"data %@",urlData);
    [self clearNotifications];   
 }
```

The above same code was working fine previously now its not working I'm not able to find solution why its not storing after i changing to new account please tell me how to resolve.

Thanks.

Comment: Well there is nothing much to go on, is the request being received by your server? Is the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` firing? You will need to debug these before we can help your.

Comment: i have tried this nofication code is not excuting please tell me now to resolve this one

Comment: @rckoenes its showing lauchoption NSDictionay * nil

Comment: Are getting any of the log messages in your didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov no im not getting any message in my console pervioulsy it was showing now its not

Comment: So lets be clear. You delete the app, the run it again from xcode so you can request to register for remote notification. Alert view pops up asking you if you agree to receive notifications from your app, you click yes and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: is not getting called. Is that correct?

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov no its not even asking alert view popup pervioulsy its the way its doing but code its self not working please tell me how to resolve this one

Comment: Are you testing this on a device, or simulator. Is this iOS 7? Are you implementing '-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error' ?

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov ya im testing in device only s im using ios5 im not implementing didfailtoregister method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51410/discussion-between-panayot-panayotov-and-user3427551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for other people reading this question. We have narrowed down the issue by implementing

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```

After that it turns out that the app was signed with wrong provisioning profile. Simple things like that are getting missed :)